# Refactor firebase function index.ts code so that triggers can be imported

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am writing firebase functions with `https`, `auth`, and `datastore` triggers, so I would like to factor them out to different files. I have factored out the `https` functions but I am not sure how to factor out the `auth` function. My `index.ts` is currently:

```
import * as express     from 'express';
import * as functions   from 'firebase-functions';
import  { spiceAdmin  } from './base';
import  { spiceServer } from './spiceServer'

import  { server }      from './api-routes/api'


exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(server);



/**
    @Use: send verification email on new user creation
*/
exports.onCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate( user => {

    spiceAdmin.auth().createUser({
          email         : 'user-auth-ts@gmail.com'
        , emailVerified : false
        , password      : 'Sup3rSafe'
    }) 
    .then((userRecord : any) => console.log('created new user'))
    .catch((err : string) => console.log(`failed to create new user with ${err}`))

});
```

Specifically, if I had a file `user_auth.ts` with triggers `onCreate` and `onChange`, how would I *syntactically* write those functions, export then, and `exports....` them in `index.ts?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

index.ts

```
import { myFunction } from './myfunction'
export const myFunction_export = myFunction
```

myfunction.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
export const myFunction = functions.firestore.document(...).onCreate(...)
```